# Erro ao compilar LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

Ao tentar compilar um código **[LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org)** deu o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Por favor, dê mais detalhes sobre o programa que você está usando para rodar sua aplicação java ou se está partindo diretamente do *cmd*. Talvez haja algum problema com a maneira como sua aplicação foi exportada ou com os argumentos que você está usando para rodá-la; um caso comum é o uso do argumento `Xmx` com um valor que indique mais memória do que o disponível.